# How to search document in specified folder with Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I want to search documents in specified folder. I mean ,as in below case, searching documents of mainfolder1.
How can I do this?? With lucene possible?? I know lucene can specify store. I don't know about folder.

-->company home

---->mainfolder1

------->doc1

------->doc2

---->mainfolder2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like

```
+PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:mainfolder1//."
```

is what you want in your search expression.

The full glory details about Alfresco search in general in path queries in particular are at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Path_Queries

Answer (score 0):

Correct is

PATH:"/app:company_home/cm:mainfolder1/*"

as you do not need to search nodes at any depth but only direct children of main folder1.

You can find additional explanations here

http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/07/09/alfresco-lucene-tutorial/